# How to get this script trigger before the page loads

Tags: javascript

I want this script to be executed before the page is shown to the user so that the user does not see the page to be adjusted in real time.

Can anyone help?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            onResize();
            $(window).resize(function () {
                onResize();
            });
        });
        function onResize() {
            var w = $(window).width();
            var ratio = 1;
            if (w < 1920) {
                ratio = (w / 1920);
            }
            if (isTablet()) {
                ratio = ratio * 1.25;
            }
            if (isMobile()) {
                ratio = ratio * 3;
            }

            $('body').css('font-size', ratio + 'px');
        }

        function isTablet() {
            if ($('.tablet:visible').length > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        function isMobile() {
            if ($('.mobile:visible').length > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Well you could use stylesheets to get it within the ballpark so the jump is not huge. Or just use `vw`

Comment: JS is unnecessary. Use CSS @media

Answer (score 3):

what you're trying to do with Javascript could be easily done with css only and the usage of [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). I would suggest you to learn about them instead of using "hacks" to do something that is not the regular behaviour of a web page

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS to hide page content, and then execute this code, and then display page content.